# How to use invert match regex in sed? like grep

Tags: bash, scripts, grep, sed

How can I use invert match regex like grep -v ?

I want invernt

```
sed '/[Ss][0-9]*[Ee][0-9]*/d' ${Src}
```

like

```
grep -ev '[Ss][0-9]*[Ee][0-9]*' ${Src}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean `grep -ve '[Ss][0-9]*[Ee][0-9]*'` (since `grep -ev '[Ss][0-9]*[Ee][0-9]*'` would try to match pattern `v` in a file named `[Ss][0-9]*[Ee][0-9]*`).

If so, then remember that `sed '/pattern/d'` is *already* an inverse match - by deleting the lines that **do** match the pattern, it prints those that do **not** match. If you want to invert *that* (i.e. the equivalent of plain `grep -e 'pattern'`) then you can use either

```
sed '/[Ss][0-9]*[Ee][0-9]*/!d'
```

(delete lines that **don't** match `[Ss][0-9]*[Ee][0-9]*` i.e. print ones that **do**) or more straightforwardly disable the default print, then print matching lines only, i.e.

```
sed -n '/[Ss][0-9]*[Ee][0-9]*/p'
```